# Single instance of a JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I have a bunch of JInternalFrames that are need to be added to a JDesktopPane, all JIFs are related to each others, each JIF has a next button when I press the next button I want the current JIF to be replaced with a new one; that means the old one should be dispose.
Now I wonder how to dispose the old JInternalFrame, I thought it would be nice If I could keep a single instance of a JIF and always check if its not nulll then dispose it, but this is not working for me.

you guys have any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure why you cant use Jinternalframe.[dispose()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#dispose%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you cant use Jinternalframe.[dispose()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#dispose%28%29)

Comment: tnx for the reply, I can use dispose() but when I want to initialize new JIF to my instance than its not working anymore:  e.g; JInternalFrame main = null;  main = new MyJInternalFrame1(); main = new MyJInternalFrame2(); now I can't dispose() MyJInternalFrame2